# import and rename functions from a folder - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to use variables (strings) in the import statement but cannot get the job done with importlib. How can I use variables with `import from as`, or how can importlib be used for the full `import from as` functionality?

## My case:

The majority of our import statements have repetitive strings in them. It looks something like this:

```
from somemodule import someclass
from mainfolder.submodule1 import rep_functionC as functionC
from mainfolder.submodule3 import rep_trickA as trickA
from mainfolder.submodule2 import rep_specialB as specialB
..etc
```

I'd like to cut out the repetitive parts in mainfolder in a function like `simport()`:

```
from somemodule import someclass

import simport
things_to_import = "a list or dictionary of submodules in the main folder,
                    and functions beginning with rep_"
simport(things_to_import)
```

Since the import/from statements take everything very literal, I haven't been able to use:

```
def simport( module, function):
  s1 = "mainfolder." + module
  s2 = "rep_" + function
  import s1 from s2 as function
```

and haven't been able to get importlib to perform all these actions.