# How can I change the name of a group of imports in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I would like to import all methods from a module with altered names.

For instance, instead of

```
from module import repetitive_methodA as methodA, \
    repetitive_Class1 as Class1, \
    repetitive_instance4 as instance4
```

I'd prefer something along the lines of

```
from module import * as *-without-"repetitive_"
```

this is a rephrasing of this [clumsy unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772827/import-and-rename-functions-from-a-folder-python-3), I have not been able to find a solution or similar questions yet.

Comment: Since you yourself have admitted that you've posted two similar questions, please do something about the other one. (i.e. delete it or mark it as a duplicate of this one.)

Comment: Perhaps you should build your own import function using `imp` module from the standard library.

Comment: @Aran-Fey done!

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi will try this now

Comment: take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997274/changing-import-name-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do it this way:

```
import module
import inspect
for (k,v) in inspect.getmembers(module):
    if k.startswith('repetitive_'):
        globals()[k.partition("_")[2]] = v
```

*Edit in response to the comment "how is this answer intended to be used?"*

Suppose `module` looks like this:

```
# module
def repetitive_A():
    print ("This is repetitive_A")

def repetitive_B():
    print ("This is repetitive_B")
```

Then after running the rename loop, this code:

```
A()
B()
```

produces this output:

```
This is repetitive_A
This is repetitive_B
```

Comment: Using this I haven't been able to write my code as ```methodA(args)``` instead of ```repetitive_methodA(args)```. I may be missing something, how is this answer intended to be used?

Comment: Two things to try. Add 2 `print()` calls to the `for` loop that says what functions are getting new names, such as `print("Renaming",k)`. Put one before the `if` and one after. That will tell you if your `if` test is doing what it should. After the code runs, `print(globals().keys())` to see if the names you are adding to `globals()` are what you expect.

Comment: Confirmed, it works, thank you very much! Sadly A() or B() remain unresolved references in my editor, but that is another question.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please accept it. The editor is clearly doing static analysis and is (unsurprisingly) foxed by the operations on `globals()`. But if you put this code in `module2` and then in a third file do `from module2 import *` that will probably make your editor happy.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, creating a work-around...

Including you have a file named `some_file.py` in the current directory, which is composed of...

```
# some_file.py
def rep_a():
    return 1

def rep_b():
    return 2

def rep_c():
    return 3
```

---

When you import something, you create an **object** on which you call methods. These methods are the classes, variables, functions of your file.

In order to get what you want, I thought It'd be a great idea to just add a **new object**, containing the original functions you wanted to rename. The function `redirect_function()` takes an object as first parameter, and will **iterate** through the methods (in short, which are the functions of your file) of this object : it will, then, create another object which will contain the pointer of the function you wanted to rename at first.

tl;dr : this function will create another object which contains the original function, but the original name of the function will **also** remain.

See example below. :)

```
def redirect_function(file_import, suffixe = 'rep_'):
    #   Lists your functions and method of your file import.
    objects = dir(file_import)

    for index in range(len(objects)):
        #   If it begins with the suffixe, create another object that contains our original function.
        if objects[index][0:len(suffixe)] == suffixe:
            func = eval("file_import.{}".format(objects[index]))
            setattr(file_import, objects[index][len(suffixe):], func)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import some_file
    redirect_function(some_file)
    print some_file.rep_a(), some_file.rep_b(), some_file.rep_c()
    print some_file.a(), some_file.b(), some_file.c()
```

This outputs...

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks, this is getting close! Is it possible to remove the module reference from this? So instead of ```some_file.a()``` we end up with ```a()```? This final solution has been so hard to find, I'm starting to think it's 'un-pythonic' or something..

Comment: That is _indeed_ possible. But I think you'd need to use another `eval()`. If you are in a safe environment in which you haven't got user inputs, and/or your `eval()` are out of reach of an online environment, you can use it. Instead of doing the line with `setattr()`, you'd need to do : `eval("{} = func".format(objects[index][len(suffixe):]))` AND you shouldn't do this in a function, OR you would need to declare your variable as a global.

Comment: I believe this is non-pythonic **indeed** because if you want a function to have another name... rename it ? Either using **as**, or in the source code..